# ¿Cómo imprimir una tabla en pdf en iTextSharp c#?

Tags: c#

Alguien sabe como convertir una matriz en formato de tabla para luego convertirla en pdf?

Gracias.

Comment: Hola @FangusK si, sabemos, pero, ¿Qué has intentado para lograr lo que planteas? Te recomiendo darte una pasada por [El tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/Tour) para que aprendas como funciona el sitio y [Como elaboro una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita tu pregunta con lo que has hecho para poderte ayudar!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que esto

[iTextSharp - Introducing Tables](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/86/itextsharp-introducing-tables)

podria ayudarte, como veras la idea es que recorreas la matriz para poder generar celdas que agregas a la tabla del documento

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

table.AddCell("Col 1 Row 1");

//resto celdas

doc.Add(table);
```